# Can NSNumber class method discern between signed and unsigned int?

Tags: objective-c

Is there any way to probe an NSNumber to see if it is an int or unsigned int.  I have tried to do this with objCType, but I can't tell the difference.  Consider the following scenario:

```
NSNumber *number1 = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:100];
NSNumber *number2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:100];

NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[number1 objCType]]);
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[number2 objCType]]);
```

Output:
i
i

Does any one know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objCType` doesn't guarantee that the type it returns will be the same as the type you put in.

What you're trying to do essentially ignores the point of `NSNumber`, which is to avoid the clumsiness with which numerical values need to be treated in C. By wrapping a numerical value in an `NSNumber`, you can compare it with any other such value without regard to their "actual" (bit-wise) types, and you can get the value back in a different "actual" type than you started with.*

It doesn't give you back the exact same type because it doesn't need to -- you put in whatever you want and take out whatever you want. The type of a C variable isn't known at run-time, anyways.

I guess you have to use `NSNumber` because you need to stick numerical values into a Cocoa collection? You may have to wrap the `NSNumber` in your own object that also keeps a record of the initial type. This will require a long `switch` or a bunch of `if`/`else`s...

---

<sub>* The only caveat here is that now you must be concerned again with the size of the type: trying to put a value bigger than `FLT_MAX` into a `float`, for example, gives you garbage.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Why is this a problem?

NSNumber, simply put, doesn't care if the number is unsigned or signed, and will coerce or convert as necessary; just as it doesn't care if the number is fixed or floating point.

The type of the number only really matters in creation.

Comment: I have a program where I know what type of number it is at creation.  But I may later access this number, and I need to know how to type it at access.  If you can think of a more elegant way of doing this, I am open to suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

No. Under the hood `NSNumber` uses `CFNumber`, and the latter does not store unsigned values - the NSNumber methods check the value passed in and if it is too large to fit in a signed type of the same size it uses the next larger signed type. (And yes, if you store a large unsigned 64 bit integer `NSNumber` uses an internal 128-bit signed integer.)

If you want to keep track of the original type you will have to do so yourself, e.g. create an object with a field for the type and a field for the number...

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the `NSNumber` using category.

```
@implements NSNumber (Signed)
    - (BOOL)isNumberSigned {
        // Test if number less than zero
        // return the result
    }
```

That is the beauty of Objective-C; very simple to extend a class.

Answer (score 0):

Using `[- doubleValue]`, `[- stringValue]` or `[- decimalValue]` can reveal if the original value was negative when created using a signed init method.
I am surprised there is no simple `- wasCreatedSigned` functionality.

```
BOOL negTest;
negTest = ([myNSNumber doubleValue] < 0);                 // <0.1 micro sec
negTest = [[myNSNumber stringValue] hasPrefix:@"-"];      // >1.5 micro sec
negTest = ([myNSNumber decimalValue]._isNegative);        // >2.5 micro sec
negTest = ([myNSDecimalNumber decimalValue]._isNegative); // <0.1 micro sec
```

Internally NSNumber IS aware of the signed state of its value.

As for `-objCType` I've noticed it will not always reflect the init type as the documentation says. But it will accurately distinguish floats/doubles (d) away from integers (c, s, i, q, Q...).

Here is some code to play with, it will reveal some oddities (tested on iOS 4.3):

```
void isNeg(NSNumber* num, NSString* initMethod);
void isNeg(NSNumber* num, NSString* initMethod)
{
    printf("\r");
    NSLog(@"%@ (class:%@)", initMethod, [num class]);

    double dval = [num doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"Is Negative:%c, objCType:%s", (dval<0)?'Y':'N', [num objCType]);
    NSLog(@"strVal: %@", [num stringValue]);
    NSLog(@"%%f    : %f", dval);
    NSLog(@"%%g    : %g", dval);
    NSLog(@"%%lld  : %lld", [num longLongValue]);
    NSLog(@"%%llu  : %llu", [num unsignedLongLongValue]);
}

// main...
double testDouble = 10001e-9;
Class nc = [NSNumber class];

isNeg([nc numberWithChar:    -1], @"Char");
isNeg([nc numberWithChar:    -2], @"Char");
isNeg([nc numberWithChar:    -3], @"Char");
isNeg([nc numberWithChar:     1], @"Char");
isNeg([nc numberWithChar:    12], @"Char");
isNeg([nc numberWithChar:    13], @"Char");
isNeg([nc numberWithUnsignedChar: 12], @"UChar");
isNeg([nc numberWithUnsignedChar: 13], @"UChar");

isNeg([nc numberWithLongLong:        -LONG_LONG_MAX], @"LongLong");
isNeg([nc numberWithLongLong:         LONG_LONG_MAX], @"LongLong");
isNeg([nc numberWithUnsignedLongLong: ULONG_LONG_MAX], @"ULongLong");

isNeg([nc numberWithDouble:-LONG_LONG_MAX], @"Double");
isNeg([nc numberWithDouble: ULONG_LONG_MAX], @"Double");

isNeg([nc numberWithDouble:-testDouble], @"Double");
isNeg([nc numberWithDouble: testDouble], @"Double");

nc = [NSDecimalNumber class];
isNeg([nc numberWithDouble:-testDouble], @"Double");
isNeg([nc numberWithDouble: testDouble], @"Double");
```