# NSNumber; signed or unsigned?

Tags: ios, nsnumber

Is there anyway to determine if an NSNumber is of type UnsignedInt or just Int?

Comment: you can take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811136/can-nsnumber-class-method-discern-between-signed-and-unsigned-int).

Answer (score 3):

No. From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (emphasis mine)

> NSNumber is a subclass of NSValue that offers a value as any C scalar
>   (numeric) type. It defines a set of methods specifically for setting
>   and accessing the value as a signed or unsigned char, short int, int,
>   long int, long long int, float, or double or as a BOOL. **(Note that
>   number objects do not necessarily preserve the type they are created
>   with.)** It also defines a compare: method to determine the ordering of
>   two NSNumber objects.